# How to configure Windows 7 for high responsiveness 24 hours a day?

Tags: windows-7, performance-tuning

When Windows 7 operating systems is used one a production line, then it has to be configured appopriately. We do not want various services interfering with the software that has to be working with highest performance 24 hours a day (something like image analysis at 30 frames per second).

My question is: which system services for Windows 7 should be turned off in such an environment.

I already have on my list:

- disk defragmentation
- file indexing
- any anti-virus software

Answer (score 3):

> which system services for Windows 7 should be turned off in such an
>   environment

Well, sorry to be Captain Obvious, but that largely depends on which services your software is dependent on.

Also, keep in mind that both software and driver packages, often come packaged with "helper" tools (and sometimes just crapware), that auto starts. These are often not necessary, so you might want to disable those as well.

[Sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) provides a nice overview of just how much starts automatically one way or the other, be that services, items in the "Start" start menu folder or Run/RunOnce entries in registry.

Services aside, be sure to activate the "High Performance" power plan. This ensures amongst other things, that processor, GPU and network can run at full throttle. More importantly for 24/7 operation pehaps, it disables sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It may really depend on your bottlenecks - Having lots of ram, and possibly ramdisks, and an SSD (or two) may make a bigger difference than performance tuning. Unless your system is isolated from the rest of the world, AV of some sort may be a better idea than not.

I wouldn't normally suggest a link as an answer but blackviper has a [pretty extensive list](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) of services and what they do on his website. Considering you're doing image identification, some of the things that would be removed in his setups may be needed, so some testing is required.

On the other hand, there is already a stripped down version of windows in [windows server core](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184075.aspx) - which may be worth considering as an alternative. Its significantly more expensive, but you'd have fewer restrictions in terms of the hardware you can use, and it already starts with a fairly uncrappified installation.

Answer (score -1):

> When Windows 7 operating systems is used one a production line, then it has to be configured 
>   appopriately.

Actually no. It has not. It is not made for that and using it in this environment is unprofessional. Want a server, use a server. If you need an embedded system, get windows embedded.

Any of those services you name have a sense. You can not just turn them off and then come back here complaining about the consequences.

Comment: I have to disagree. Windows 7 builds on the same foundation as Windows Server 2008R2. It doesn't sound to me like @Michael is in need for any of the server features, and he will get the same stability with Windows 7. Also, I don't see any need to get into the Embedded world, with different licensing model, support options, included features etc.